# Having problem with IronPython to instantiate a class in IronPython Console

Tags: python, ironpython

I'm trying to learn IronPython.  I created an extremely simple class like this one:

```
class Test:
  def testMethod(self):
    print "test"
```

Next I'm trying to use it in IronPython Console:

```
>>> import Test
>>> t = Test()
```

After the second line I get following error:

> TypeError: Scope is not callable

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to `from filename import Test` where filename is a basename of file class Test is saved in.

e.g.: class `Test` is saved in  `test.py`

then:

```
from test import Test
t = Test()
```

will run as expected.

Comment: that's did it.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

`import Test` loads the module named Test, defined in a file called Test.py(c|d). This module in turn contains your class named Test. You're trying to instantiate the module called Test. To instantiate the class Test in module Test, you need to use:

t = Test.Test()

This concept can be quite tricky, especially if you have a background in other languages. Took me a while to figure out too :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  You're absolutely correct.  Too bad I had to accept only one answer. SlientGhost was first.  +1 for you.